# Hide/Show ProgressBar using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, xml, android-asynctask

I'm trying to do the simple act of hiding/showing ProgressBar according to AsyncTask state  , 
I have two classes one extends FragmentActivity and second AsyncTask.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public static ProgressBar mProgressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // What will happen to the progress bar here?  
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
  // What will happen to the progress bar here? 
}

       @Override
        protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

      // What will happen to the progress bar here? 
    }
    }
```

MyAsyncTask.java

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground() {
    // start download some images from cloud 
    // Here the progress bar should start to appear in MainActivity
    // mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Finished book downloading images the cloud");
   // Here the progress bar should start to disappear in MainActivity
   // mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


}

}
```

main_activity.xml

```
      <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true" />
```

Hope you understand me, thank to everyone who can help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog?rq=1 this can solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

The progress bar should appear in **onPreExecute()** method (still in UI thread). Then you dismiss it when you get back to UI thread in **onPostExecute** method.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, Void> {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute(Void result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Finished book downloading images the cloud");
   // Here the progress bar should start to disappear in MainActivity
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground() {
// start download some images from cloud 
// there is a time cost operation


}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Finished book downloading images the cloud");
   // Here the progress bar should start to disappear in MainActivity
   // mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


}

}
```

You should use onPreExecute() method to show the dialog.

Here is MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
}
```

I think you should read [APIs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) first.

Answer (score 0):

Use preExecute and postExecute methods as they run on UI thread.

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, Void> {

ProgressBar pBar;
@Override
protected void onPreExecute(Void result) {
pBar=new ProgressBar(getContext());
pBar.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   if(pBar !=null and pBar.isShowing()){
  pBar.dismiss();
}
}

}
```

Comment: It's two different classes, I dont understand how it works?

Comment: create constructor in your `MyAsyncTask` and pass `context` as argument in your constructor and then use that context to build `progressBar` then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use interface in Asyntask class for communicate with Activity class

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

//use context for activity reference
private Context context_;

public MyAsyncTask(Context context) {
    this.context_=context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    if(mCallBack!=null ){
        mCallBack.onSuccess("Success");
    }else {
        mCallBack.onError("Error");

    }
}

MyAsyncCallBack mCallBack=null;

public MyAsyncCallBack getmCallBack() {
    return mCallBack;
}

public void setmCallBack(MyAsyncCallBack mCallBack) {
    this.mCallBack = mCallBack;
}

public interface MyAsyncCallBack{
    public void onSuccess(String successMessage);
    public void onError(String successMessage);
}
```

}

Call AsynckTask Class from activity class.Before calling asyntask start progress. and after completing work in asyntask return activity via interface and hide progress.

```
startProgress();
    MyAsyncTask mTask=new MyAsyncTask(YourActivity.this);
    mTask.setmCallBack(new MyAsyncTask.MyAsyncCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String successMessage) {
            //do success work and hide progress
            hideProgress();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String successMessage) {
            //do error work and hide progress
            hideProgress();
        }
    });
    mTask.execute();
```